# SQL - select muliple rows if search criteria matches one of the Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Apologies if already asked but not too sure what to search for. I want to select muliple LocaleIds if search criterial matches one of the Values.

Currently I am doing simple search like this:

```
SELECT *
   FROM [dbo].[Localizations]
   WHERE Value like 'task switching' OR ResourceId like 'task switching'
   ORDER BY LocaleId, ResourceId
```

This results in:

```
Id      ResourceId                      Value            LocaleId
53591   AssessmentType_Description_21   Task Switching  
53247   Attribute_Description_1         Task Switching  
53378   Attribute_Description_132       Task Switching
```

However this is missing the associated rows for the Other LocaleIds (English LocaleId is blank ' '). For example, I require:

```
Id      ResourceId                      Value                  LocaleId
53591   AssessmentType_Description_21   Task Switching  
53247   Attribute_Description_1         Task Switching  
53378   Attribute_Description_132       Task Switching  
42257   AssessmentType_Description_21   Aufgabenwechsel         de
42839   Attribute_Description_1         Aufgabenwechsel         de
42876   Attribute_Description_132       Aufgabenwechsel         de
45864   AssessmentType_Description_21   Changement de tâches    fr
46446   Attribute_Description_1         Changement de tâches    fr
46483   Attribute_Description_132       Changement de tâches    fr
```

How can I get the full results set for all LocaleIds? Any help appreciated.

Edit:
Sorry I want all the records that match 'Task switching' and their corresponding values in other languages. Will only ever be searching in 1 language.

Comment: Surely you just remove your where clause? In your example from what I can gather you want all of your 3rd code segment, which aren't all 'LIKE task switching'

Comment: But that would give me everything in table?

Comment: ok now I get it

Comment: Okay I see what you mean now, you might have to filter it differently as you're just returning records with task switiching

Comment: `SELECT *
   FROM [dbo].[Localizations]
   WHERE ResourceId  in (SELECT ResourceId FROM [dbo].[Localizations] WHERE Value like 'task switching') 
   ORDER BY LocaleId, ResourceId `

Comment: Task Switching  isn't int he value or ResourceID column in the other rows. Why would you expect them to be returned?

Comment: Thanks @Take_Care for understanding, if you give answer i will mark as correct :)

Comment: This question is very unclear, are you saying you want all of the records with matching resourceid where one of the resourceid has a value = 'task switching'? edit: seems so from the latest response

Comment: Sorry I want all the records that match 'Task switching' and their corresponding values in other languages

Comment: confusing question. Do update your question.

Comment: Not sure how else to word it to be honest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this SQL will resolve Your Problem :

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Localizations] 
WHERE ResourceId in (SELECT ResourceId 
                     FROM [dbo].[Localizations] 
                     WHERE Value like 'task switching') 
ORDER BY LocaleId, ResourceId
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend EXISTS here, instead of IN:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Localizations loc
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT 1
 FROM dbo.Localizations loc2
 WHERE value LIKE 'task switching'
 AND loc.resourceID = loc2.resourceid)
ORDER BY localeid, resourceid
```

This way should run faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AND` to combine multiple operators.

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Localizations]
WHERE Value like 'task switching'
AND Value like 'aufgabenwechsel'
AND Value like 'changement de tâches'
ORDER BY LocaleId, ResourceId
```

Keep in mind that special characters like 'â' sometimes aren't accepted in your SQL statements, therefore I would suggest you look into  [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: thanks but, only ever going to be searching in one language.